# Add html layout to a blank aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to create dynamic html layout without any asp controls. Actually I want to leave on aspx page only the first line

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Kletka._Default" %>
```

and the generate full html layout on codebehind. Advise pls how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...you want to use ASP.NET web forms without using the built in controls like GridView and so on, at all?

You can write your html and use protected properties?
<%= SomeWhereText %?

or to have the FULL html layout in the code behind make a property

```
protected string MyEntirePage {get;set;}
```

and build the string in the code behind

```
MyEntirePage="<h1>Hello</h1><p>body here</p><p>the end</p>";
```

and write it out in the aspx page via

```
<%=MyEntirePage%>
```

Re: "I've got your point, but I really don't like asp.net controls. I'd prefer to use html controls and customize them with js"

Install NancyFx or maybe the old (but still great) WCF Web Api and use something like KnockoutJs, jQuery or Backbone to perform ajax calls for the dynamic content = no asp.net web forms at all. Yay.

Comment: I hate being down voted without being told where I've gone wrong. How can I improve my answers without feedback...

Answer (score 1):

One way is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     string coolHTML = @"<div class=""someclass"">... and other cool content</div>";
     Response.Write(coolHTML);
}
```

With that said. This is a terrible idea. Constructing HTML dynamically on code behind is a nightmare to maintain, it doesn't perform as best as it can and you lose many other features that asp.net offers, which are the main reason to use ASP.NET in the first place.

What you can do is create User controls for specific things (footer, header, left panel, etc) and define a layout for them in markup; then on Code behind, you can add them to specific place holders in the page, depending on some business conditions.

Assuming you have a master page (or at least some content place holders in the page) as so:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="footer" runat="Server" />
```

On code behind you can do:

```
footer.Controls.Add(new FooterControl());
```

**Update** OP just mentioned in the comments that he doesn't like asp.net controls...

You don't **have to** use ASP.NET controls, you can use regular HTML controls and set their `runat="server"` attribute if you need to be able to manipulate their properties on server-side. For example:

```
<div id="mydiv" runat="server" > some content </div>
```

On Code behind:

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("class","css_class");
myDiv.Attributes.Add("onclick","callJavascriptFunction();");
// and so on.
```

It's okay to do this sort of thing *occasionally* under very specific circumstances but I'd avoid this sort of code because is difficult to maintain. Imagine you need to add another class to the `myDiv` element, for example. Now, you'd have to change you code as opposed to just changing your markup...

Comment: I've got your point, but I really don't like asp.net controls. I'd prefer to use html controls and customize them with js.

Comment: Then why don't you just use HTML controls on the aspx page?

Comment: I'm creating not single page application. I want to develop a site. And parsing url (several get params) load different content.

Comment: @Ars I'd still create definitive markup for all these "views". You are shooting yourself in the foot if you plan to generate the actual html rendered to the client on the server side.

Comment: I decided to use fully Ajax based site. I will render content in special dynamic content div using jquery Ajax etc. Thanks for advise.

Comment: Why are you afraid to use asp.net controls?  You can still do whatever you like in JS on them.  Why use .NET at all then?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to dynamically add the controls in the Page_Init event.  So you need a container to hold your HTML, so you should start by adding a Panel to the Page, then the page's controls would get added to the Panel.

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
Page.Controls.Add(pnl);


TextBox txt = new TextBox();
pnl.Controls.Add(txt);
```

etc....